# edit stored data in local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am getting the content of a div from my page and storing it to the local storage (the content of the div are variable, dependent of the user input)

```
 var content= document.getElementById('tobestoreddiv').innerHTML;//get the content
 localStorage.setItem("content", content);// store the content
```

I want to remove the function from some of the divs inside the `content` div. Some of them have `onclick` events and so on..

I have tried using `.replace()` to remove some of the tags and functions as follows:

```
var changedinnerhtml = localStorage.getItem("content");
changedinnerhtml = changedinnerhtml.replace('autoplay="" loop=""', 'autoplay loop muted');//for videos, idk why the tags are set to =""
changedinnerhtml = changedinnerhtml.replace('contenteditable="true"', ''); // as an example for tags
changedinnerhtml = changedinnerhtml.replace('onclick="function();"', ''); // as an example for functions
document.body.innerHTML = changedinnerhtml; // this is displaying on another page
```

But this method isn't working is there another way to remove the functions and tags?

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
               function replaceAll(source, search, replace, ignoreCase) {
                    //SCAPE SPECIAL CHARACTERES.
                    var search1 = this.regExpEscapeSpecialCharacters(search);
                    //IGNORE CASE SENSIVITY.
                    var ignore = (ignoreCase) ? "gi" : "g";
                    var result = source.replace(new RegExp(search1, ignore), replace);
                    return result;
                    
                }

                var changedinnerhtml = localStorage.getItem("content");
                changedinnerhtml = replaceAll(changedinnerhtml, 'autoplay="" loop=""', 'autoplay loop muted', true);//for videos, idk why the tags are set to =""
                changedinnerhtml = replaceAll(changedinnerhtml, 'contenteditable="true"', '', true); // as an example for tags
                changedinnerhtml = replaceAll(changedinnerhtml, 'onclick="function();"', '', true); // as an example for functions
                document.body.innerHTML = changedinnerhtml; // this is displaying on another page
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be more defensive about which attributes you *do* want to have on your element. Create a list of attributes, note that empty values (`muted=""`) are the same as having no values at all `muted`, so don't worry about removing those.

```js
const localStorageResult = `<div class='some-class' contenteditable="true" autoplay="" loop="" muted="" some-other-attribute onclick='function() { alert("Click"); }'>Hello world</div>`;

const copyAttributes = [
  'class',
  'autoplay',
  'loop',
  'muted'
];

// Create a dummy element
var containerElement = document.createElement( 'div' );

// This parses the element, so it becomes valid HTML
containerElement.innerHTML = localStorageResult;
const storedElement = containerElement.firstElementChild;

const elementType = storedElement.tagName;
const newElement = document.createElement(elementType);

copyAttributes
  .filter((attribute) => storedElement.hasAttribute(attribute))
  .forEach((attribute) => {
    newElement.setAttribute(attribute, storedElement.getAttribute(attribute));
  });

document.body.appendChild(newElement);
```

```css
.some-class {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```